# Rename WCF Service Name & Binding Name

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

**Assumption:** 
I'm working with a WCF application called DemoWCF, in which I have a simple wcf service called Calculator.

The purpose of the application is obviously a demo, the WCF service has to take two numbers as parameters and make the sum of them.

*Service Class:*

```
public class Calculator : ICalculator
{
    public int Sum(int firstValue, int secondValue)
    {
        return firstValue + secondValue;
    }
}
```

*Service Contract :*

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://ROCKET/Calculator")]
public interface ICalculator
{
    [OperationContract]
    int Sum(int firstValue, int secondValue);
}
```

*Web.config, service model configuration:*

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="wsHttpsBinding">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
        <service name="DemoWCF.Services.ServiceClasses.Calculator">
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpsBinding" contract="DemoWCF.Services.ServiceContracts.ICalculator" />
        </service>
    </services>     

    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

When I deploy the WCF application on my IIS and I try to consume the WCF service in SOAP UI or in an ASP.NET MVC application, everything works fine.

**Goal:** 
When I consume the WCF service in SOAP UI, I note that from the wsdl of the web service is automatically generated the binding "WSHttpBinding_ICalculator".

[image]

When I consume the WCF service in an ASP.NET MVC application, I note that the from the wsdl of the web service is automatically generated the service model, precisely:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ICalculator">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://rocket/ServiceClasses/Calculator.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ICalculator" contract="Calculator.ICalculator" name="WSHttpBinding_ICalculator" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

What I want to do, is to rename the Service Name and the Binding Name of the WCF Service.

It's possibile to omit this WCF behavior of generating binding's name with the format : "BindingType_IServiceInterface" ?

What I have to do, if I want to rename my service name and binding name in "Calculator" ?

Comment: Why do you want to rename them?  Is there some functional or business reason driving that?  If not, I'd recommend just leaving it as is, as the amount of effort it may take (if it can be done) would seem to far outweigh the benefits.

Comment: Let's say that is just an aesthetic request from one of my customers.
We are both curious to know if it is possible to omit this WCF behavior to call both Service name and Binding name with a different name than the service class.
Obviously part of the request is to find a simple way, without upset the web service and without rewriting too much rows of code.